# Trouble merging branches in xcode source control

Tags: xcode, git, version-control

I'm trying to merge a branch of my project into the trunk. It's like chasing my tail, insisting that I have uncommitted changes in one branch or the other, but I can't find them. The merge button seems to be permanently dimmed. I try looking through the files listed in the left side of the merge panel, but can't figure out how to resolve the conflicts (the conflicts appear to be resolved already). So I right click on a file and get this popup:

[image]

I've looked around quite a bit on Google and SO, and can't find out what those commands mean. Neither option turns the merge button on.

I'm using El Capitan and Xcode 7.3.1.

Would greatly appreciate any guidance.

Comment: Step out of the GUI and go command line.

Comment: The command line is deep water for me. My experience with it has been limited to following explicit instructions for, say, adding CocoaPods to my project. Can you give me any guidance or point me to some instructions?

Comment: There are lots on the web, just search for "git beginners" or "git tutorial". You can also try some git GUI clients. I like Atlassian's SourceTree, https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/. Its also free.

Comment: I just DLd and registered SourceTree. Since my project is already under Source Control via Xcode, will I be doing anything dangerous by creating a repo in SourceTree and adding the project?

Comment: No, you will point SourceTree to the existing repo, so nothing new is created. Just add the project to SourceTree and you might use that for all your souce control activities as I think its much better and its sole purpose is to present a nice GUI wrapper on top of Git as opposed to XCode which has become a kitchen sink kind thing.

Comment: For anyone else reading, there are plenty of other GUI git clients to try if SourceTree isnt your thing. I just downloaded it and its worked out for me.

Comment: @DavidN-- Many thanks for your help! I added the existing repo by scanning the folder that holds my project. I'm pretty nervous about doing anything further though, because SourceTree only lists the "master," and not the branch I've been working on the past week and that I want to merge back into the master. I know the comment section isn't for extended conversations, but I'd appreciate some guidance on checking the status of the branch if you're so inclined...

Comment: So you should visually see the tree in the main upper 1/2 view in the SourceTree window. In the upper right of the SourceTree window there is a drop down that shows "master" for me. That is a dropdown, from which you can select the other branches. Git is pretty save, so you shouldnt have to worry much about losing stuff. OTOH, you have to know how to back out of things if its not what you wanted to do. Also, dont be afraid to make backups of your repo just in case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113064/discussion-between-rattletrap99-and-davidn).